# Optimize the SQL CTEs into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have three CTEs and all three are using the same source table **table1** and same join condition.
I want to merge all three into one CTE to achieve performance and get the result set efficiently.

How can I do that without impacting the result set.
the only difference among these is WHERE clause I want to merge that WHERE clause in a way that overall CTE become one

```
acc1 AS (
    select
      ta.file, 
      case when users.ename is null
        then ta.recipient 
        else concat(users.ename, '[', ta.recipient, ']') end as email_to 
    from schema1.table1 ta
    left join users on ta.recipient = users.LDAP_id 
    where ta.action like 'X' 
      and ta.recipient not like ' '
      and ta.file in (select file from head)
),

acc2 AS (
    select
      ta.file,
      isnull(
        string_agg (
          case when users.ename is null
            then ta.recipient
            else concat(users.ename,' [', ta.recipient, ']') end,
          '; '
        ),
        ''
      ) as copy_to
    from schema1.table1 ta
    left join users on ta.recipient = users.LDAP_id
    where ta.usr_flag like 'X'
      and ta.file in (select file from head)
    group by
      ta.file
), 


acc3 AS (
    select
      ta.file, 
      isnull(
        case when users.ename is null
          then ta.recipient
          else concat(users.ename, concat(users.ename,' [', ta.recipient, ']') end,
        ""
      ) as reserved_by
    from schema1.table1 ta
    left join users on ta.recipient = users.LDAP_id 
    where ta.reserved like 'X'
      and ta.file in (select file from head)
)
```

I tried to get these columns into one select, but I know about how to apply the filters

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results so that people know what your query actually does.

Comment: Merging them is unlikely to make any performance change... SQL just describes your resultset, not how the engine should obtain it. Check the execution plan for performance.

Answer (score 0):

The refactoring you propose may not be necessary to get good query efficiency. The query planner does a really good job of optimizing complex queries. It knows how to turn your overall query, with CTEs, into an abstract data flow tree, and then optimize those data flows to use appropriate indexes. You can think of (non-recursive) CTEs as simply a nice syntax for writing nested queries -- that's the way the query planner treats them.

It would be good to avoid refactoring: what you have is tested and working.

It's still possible that refactoring the query will help. But there are other things you should do first.

1. Add appropriate indexes. If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

   Create that index, then try the Actual Execution plan again to see if it comes up with another suggestion that builds on the first. Often SSMS's suggested indexes solve your performance problem. If not ...
2. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then ask a specific question asking for help with your actual execution plan.
3. That analysis may lead you to a refactoring of your query.

All that being said, you can combine `a` and `c` by merging the SELECT clauses of the two CTEs. `b` is an aggregate (GROUP BY) query, so it can't be merged with the others. Its result set inherently has a different number of rows, so you can't begin to merge it unless you know how it will be JOINed to other tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you want to merge this data. Assuming you just want a `UNION ALL`, it's pretty easy to merge `a` and `c`, but `b` is a more complicated, requiring a rather complex grouping construct, and is probably not worth merging.

Note that some of the `case` expressions have been simplified.

```sql
merged_a_and_b AS (
    select
      ta.document,

      case when ta.action like 'X'
        then isnull(
          users.ename + '[' + ta.recipient + ']',
          ta.recipient
        )
      end as email_to

      case when ta.reserved not like 'X'
        then isnull(
          isnull(
            users.ename + '[' + ta.recipient + ']',
            ta.recipient
          ),
          ""
        )
        end as reserved_by

    from schema1.table1 ta
    left join users on ta.recipient = users.LDAP_id 
    where (
          ta.action like 'X'  and ta.recipient not like ' '
       or ta.reserved like 'X'
      )
      and ta.document in (select document from head)
)
```

Assuming you wanted more of a joined style rather than a union, it's much simpler, especiially if you can aggregate all rows per `ta.document`

```sql
merged AS (
    select
      ta.document,

      string_agg(
        case when ta.action like 'X' and ta.recipient not like ' '
          then isnull(
            users.ename + '[' + ta.recipient + ']',
            ta.recipient
          )
          end,
        '; '
      ) as email_to, 

      isnull(
        string_agg (
          case when users.ename is null and ta.usr_flag like 'X'
            then ta.recipient
            else concat(users.ename,' [', ta.recipient, ']') end,
          '; '
        ),
        ''
      ) as copy_to,

      case when ta.reserved like 'X'
        then isnull(
          string_agg(
            isnull(
              users.ename + users.ename + ' [' + ta.recipient + ']',
              ta.recipient
            ),
            ''
          )
        )
        end as reserved_by

    from schema1.table1 ta
    left join users on ta.recipient = users.LDAP_id 
    where ta.reserved like 'X'
    where ta.document in (select document from head)
)
```